# praw reddit library: possible to create non-custom reports?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm trying to make a bot that auto reports posts in r/NoNewNormal. I'm running my bot with praw but I can't figure out how to make non-custom reports. It throws an exception for this subreddit because custom reports are not allowed in r/NoNewNormal. Is there any way to do this, or maybe a different python module I could be using instead.

```
import praw
from numpy import random

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='CLIENT ID',
                     client_secret='CLIENT SECRET',
                     username='MY BOTS USERNAME',
                     password='MY BOTS PASSWORD',
                     user_agent='USER AGENT')
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('NoNewNormal')

for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions():
    submission.report("Reason: Misinformation")
    link = submission.url
    print("Got one! "+ link)
```

Comment: post your code and stacktrace